# Can the_post_navigation() be outside of the loop?

Tags: posts, loop, themes, navigation

I am wondering if `the_post_navigation()` function will work properly outside the loop in single views.

For example:

```
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

  get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'single' );

endwhile;

the_post_navigation();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `the_post_navigation()` works outside of the loop on single post views.

Following the function calls, [`the_post_navigation()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_post_navigation/) uses [`get_the_post_navigation()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_navigation/) which uses `get_previous_post_link()` and `get_next_post_link()` which use [`get_adjacent_post_link()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_adjacent_post_link/) which finally uses [`get_post()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post/) which defaults to the global `$post` object.

Here's an excerpt of `get_adjacent_post_link()`:

```
function get_adjacent_post_link( $format, $link, $in_same_term = false,
    $excluded_terms = '', $previous = true, $taxonomy = 'category' ) {

    if ( $previous && is_attachment() )
        $post = get_post( get_post()->post_parent );
    else
        $post = get_adjacent_post( $in_same_term, $excluded_terms, $previous, $taxonomy );

    if ( ! $post ) {
        $output = '';
    } else {
        $title = $post->post_title;
    ...
```

Comment: Hey Dave, thank you for the detailed answer! It's helpful.